# Why is my Python regular expression checking for more than one group taking so long?

Tags: python, regex

This question originates in Django URL resolver, but the problem seems to be a general one.

I want to match URLs built like this:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6/10,11,12/
```

The regular expression I'm using is:

```
^(?P<apples>([0123456789]+,?)+)/(?P<oranges>([0123456789]+,?)+)/$
```

When I try to match it against a "valid" URL (i.e. one that matches), I get an instant match:

```
In [11]: print datetime.datetime.now(); re.compile(r"^(?P<apples>([0123456789]+,?)+)/(?P<oranges>([0123456789]+,?)+)/$").search("114,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,113,410,411,412,413/1/"); print datetime.datetime.now()
2011-10-18 14:27:42.087883
Out[11]: <_sre.SRE_Match object at 0x2ab0960>
2011-10-18 14:27:42.088145
```

However, when I try to match an "invalid" URL (non-matching), the whole regular expression takes a magnitude of time to return nothing:

```
In [12]: print datetime.datetime.now(); re.compile(r"^(?P<apples>([0123456789]+,?)+)/(?P<oranges>([0123456789]+,?)+)/").search("114,414,415,416,417,418,419,420,113,410,411,412,413/"); print datetime.datetime.now()
2011-10-18 14:29:21.011342
2011-10-18 14:30:00.573270
```

I assume there is something in the regexp engine that slows down extremely when several groups need to be matched. Is there any workaround for this? Maybe my regexp needs to be fixed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a known deficiency in many regular expression engines, including Python's and Perl's.  What is happening is the engine is backtracking and getting an exponential explosion of possible matches to try.  Better regular expression engines do not use backtracking for such a simple regular expression.

You can fix it by getting rid of the optional comma.  This is what is allowing the engine to look at a string like `123` and decide whether to parse it as `(123)` or `(12)(3)` or `(1)(23)` or `(1)(2)(3)`.  That's a lot of matches to try just for three digits, so you can see how it would explode rather quickly for a couple dozen digits.

```
^(?P<apples>[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)/(?P<oranges>[0-9]+(,[0-9]+)*)/$
```

This will make the regular expression engine always group `123,456` as `(123),(456)` and never as `(12)(3),(4)(56)` or something else.  Because it will only match in that one way, the backtracking engine won't hit a combinatorial explosion of possible parses.  Again, better regular expression engines do not suffer from this flaw.

**Update:** If I were writing it, I would do it this way:

```
^(?P<apples>[0-9,]+)/(?P<oranges>[0-9,]+)$
```

This would match a few bogus URLs (like `,/,`), but you can always return a 404 after you've parsed and routed it.

```
try:
    apples = [int(x) for x in apples.split(',')]
except ValueError:
    # return 404 error
```

Comment: RE engines that don't have this problem tend to be a bit less flexible with the types of language they accept. Stack-based RE engines are nice if they have “nice” REs, whereas automata-based RE engines deal with “nastier” REs but in a much more mysterious way. (It's very hard to add features to an automata-theoretic RE engine, because you always have to deal with all the possible ways that everything can possibly interact, which requires truly twisted programmers to understand.)

Comment: @DonalFellows: Which is why RE engines should use automata for simple REs and a backtracking engine for the feature laden ones.  It's not an either/or proposition, and it's why I was careful to qualify my statement with the clause "for such a simple regular expression".

Comment: @DietrichEpp: I'm not so sure that it's practical to do that; I worry about tricky edge cases. We're running off topic though.

Comment: @DonalFellows: It's not actually that difficult (speaking from experience).  After you parse the RE, scan the syntax tree for features the DFA engine doesn't support.  The only real trouble comes from writing two RE engines, which is twice as much code.

Answer (score 2):

You could use this regexp:

```
^(?P<apples>(?:\d+,)*\d+)/(?P<oranges>(?:\d+,)*\d+)/$
```

\d matches a digit

Comment: I actually prefer Dietrich's reply, since it puts the non-optional number to the front where it belongs, but your answer is nevertheless correct. Since I can accept only one, you are getting an upvote :)